# How to describe this region in spherical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

How can you describe the region $B$ in spherical coordinates? 
$$B=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9,\ x^2+y^2\leq z^2\ z\geq 0\}$$
[region equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6rWm.png)

Comment: What do you think? Are you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$, so the first equation becomes $r^2 \leq 9$, or $r < 3$. The second equation comes out of $x = r \sin \theta \cos \varphi$, $y = r \sin \theta \sin \varphi$ and $z = r \cos \theta$ (all important identities to memorize). Thus, we get $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \sin^2 \theta$ and $z^2 = r^2 \cos^2 \theta$. Therefore, we have $r^2 \sin^2 \theta \leq r^2 \cos^2 \theta$, or $\tan^2 \theta \leq 1$. The last equation should be self explanatory from earlier statements

Answer (score 1):

Reacalling that
$$
\begin{align}
x&=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta\;,\\
y&=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta\;,\\
z&=\rho\cos\phi\;,
\end{align}
$$
with $\rho\geq 0$, $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ and $\phi\in [0,\pi]$,
then
\begin{align}&x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9\Leftrightarrow \rho^2\leq 9\Leftrightarrow \rho\leq 3\\
&x^2+y^2\leq z^2\Leftrightarrow \rho^2\sin^2\phi\leq \rho^2\cos^2\phi\Leftrightarrow |\tan\phi|\leq 1\\
&z\geq 0\Leftrightarrow \rho\cos\phi\geq 0\Leftrightarrow \cos\phi\geq 0\end{align}
Can you take it from here?